# Extracting a specific value from a div class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `div` tag which looks something like this:

```
<div id="some id here" class="portlet portlet_15 portlet_content_15 new" >some content here</div>
```

I understand that I can get the `id` of this `div` using jquery like this:

```
$(this).closest("div").attr("id")
```

But how do I extract just the `portlet_15` from the above `class` where `15` could be any number?

Here is an extract of the code showing where I am currently getting and sending off the `id` of the `div`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some web service,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { strID:$(that).closest("div").attr("id"), strClass:"need to send the class value too right here, in this case it would be portlet_15" },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        //some error message;
    },
    success: function() {
        //some success task
    }
});
```

I have included a note in the `data` part of the code above where the `class` should go.

Comment: Those are real css clases, or you are using them to store data ? If so you should use the "data-" attribute.

Comment: @Radu Maris: They are real css classes.

Comment: You could still set data- attributes. But if you have to use classes you could get all classes and run a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code is a bit confusing, since you don't tell what `this` refers to. If it refers to your particular `div` element, then using `closest` isn't correct because that already traverses up the DOM hierarchy.

But otherwise if you'd like to get all those CSS classes of a particular element, this is what you have to call:

```
$(this).attr("class").split(" ");
// in your case this would return an array of classes:
// ["portlet", "portlet_15", "portlet_content_15", "new"]
```

`this` of course refers to the element in question. Then you can easily parse individual classes the way that you like. If you'd like to extract the number out, you'll likely use a regular expression:

```
/portlet_(\d+)/i;
```

### Use `data-` attributes

But as others suggested, getting data across would be much better if you'd do that using data-attributes as in:

```
<div id="some id here"
     class="portlet new"
     data-portlet="15"
     data-portlet-content="15">
         some content here
</div>
```

in this case both portlet-related classes are provided as data attributes, that you can easily access using:

```
$(this).data("portlet"); // would return 15
$(this).data("portletContent"); // would return 15
$(this).data("portlet-content"); // would return 15
```

The last two are variation of accessing the same data attribute with a hyphen'd name.

Comment: Was gonna add my own answer about data, but there is no need for 2 different data-attributes for portlet and portlet-content http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/VsavZ/

Comment: @Lollero: Well we don't know. Maybe there is a need for *portlet* and *portlet-content* data attributes, otherwise OP wouldn't have two CSS classes either. Anyway let them decide what's right or not.

Comment: @Lollero: BTW ref. to your demo code: underscores should only be used in IDs. CSS classes should use hyphens. HTML naming conventions.

Comment: Robert, you might get what I meant when you look at my example in my edited comment. I used underscores since the OP did, thought I personally use underscores depending on the situation. If I feel like I'd need to select part of the class as a whole, then I'd use underscore.. I.e. class="lorem_ipsum-3" Makes selection easy for the lorem_ipsum part by double clicking it..

Comment: Since you obviously didn't get my point. I'll try to explain it like this: If both values are the same, then why would you use 2 data-attributes to define the same value separately? That's like hitting 1 bird with two stones..

Comment: @Lollero: Maybe I wasn't clear either. :) Maybe there is a need for *portlet* and *portlet-content* data attributes. OP should know. Maybe the example provides the same value, but in the real world they may be different and not the same. Let OP decide what's actually needed.

Comment: P.S. Although valid point with double-click selection it's a bad excuse for not using conventions. YOu may as well write some variable in C# code as 7I_WANT_IT_TO_BE_VISIBLE` because you want that particular variable to jump out at you through out the code, but that's something you shouldn't do. Even if you're a sole developer.

Comment: Question, these data attributes, will they work in IE7 and IE8?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Of course they will. It also depends on what you mean by *will the work*. They will be accessible by `jQuery.data`, they'll be accessible by `element.getAttribute` but you won't be able to access them using `element.dataset` which is an HTML5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var c = $('#here').attr("class").split(' ')[1];
var cls = c.substr(-2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/caCPv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a regex like this:

```
var found = $('#here').attr("class").match(/portlet_\d{1,3}/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maibe using a regex:

```
var element = $(that).closest("div");
var strClass = element.attr("class").match(/portlet_\d+/i);
```

And in your ajax:

```
data: { strID: element.attr("id"), strClass: strClass[0] },
```